# Lenovo U400 overheating with fan being idle

Tags: 14.04, lenovo, overheating, fan, temperature

I've had Ubuntu 14.04 on my Lenovo U400 laptop for a year or so and everything was fine.

Suddenly yesterday I noticed when I was working on it, that it was running really hot, almost burning my left palm. It's been quite hot in my area for a couple of days so this might have triggered the temperature, I thought.

However what surprised me was that the fan was really slow. In the past it used to spin fast whenever the computer was heating too much.

I installed `lm-sensors` according to the [Ubuntu manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto). Here is the [output of `sensors-detect`](http://pastebin.com/1FWrbd0U).

This is the output at normal load:

```
szymon@lenovo:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +75.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
temp2:        +67.0°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +78.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +78.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +74.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

However, right after restarting, the results are more alarming:

```
szymon@lenovo:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +94.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
temp2:        +75.0°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +94.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +94.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +92.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

Also when I boot up Intellij Idea and Tomcat (this was no problem previously, but the fan was spinning) these are the results and the fan is idle:

```
szymon@lenovo:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +95.0°C  (crit = +98.0°C)
temp2:        +77.0°C  (crit = +126.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +96.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +96.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +95.0°C  (high = +86.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:            N/A  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)
```

This sounded quite alarming to me, so I tried to figure out how to control the fan manually to make it spin faster. I found no such option in BIOS. Then I installed `fancontrol` also according to [the manual](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SensorInstallHowto). Unfortunately, when running `sudo pwmconfig` I got the following error:

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

I tried fixing it with [this hack](https://iandwltd.wordpress.com/2014/10/12/fancontrol-under-ubuntu-14-04-resolving-usrsbinpwmconfig-there-are-no-pwm-capable-sensor-modules-installed/), which consisted of adding `acpi_enforce_resources=lax` to the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT. It didn't work, nothing changed when running `sudo pwmconfig` after updating grub and rebooting.

I also tried to turn off the switchable AMD graphics following [these instructions](http://www.lagserv.net/wp/2012/01/does-your-lenovo-ideapad-u400-run-hot-under-ubuntu-11-10/), but it didn't reduce the temperatures.

**Do you have any idea on why the fan isn't spinning faster at such temperatures or how to control it manually?**

**=== UPDATE ===**



Not sure what happened, but when I ran `sensors` today it started to show the fan's RPM value at the bottom:

```
thinkpad-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
fan1:         255 RPM
```

Anyway I now can see (and show you) the numbers of how slowly my fan is running.

Moreover, I found under [this link](http://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-acpi/msg38324.html) a guy with a similar problem. He inspired me to go check files under `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device`:

```
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ ls
driver  fan1_input  hwmon  modalias  name  power  pwm1  pwm1_enable  subsystem  uevent
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ cat fan1_input 
255
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ cat pwm1
0
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ cat pwm1_enable 
1
```

I tried running `sudo pwmconfig` again and this happened:

```
Found the following devices:                                                                                                                                                 
   hwmon0 is acpitz                                                                                                                                                          
   hwmon1 is coretemp
   hwmon2 is radeon
   hwmon3/device is thinkpad

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon3/device/pwm1           current value: 0
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: line 201: echo: write error: Operation not permitted
hwmon3/device/pwm1 stuck to 0
Manual control mode not supported, skipping hwmon3/device/pwm1.
There are no usable PWM outputs.
```

According to [this guy](http://www.tjansson.dk/2008/10/controlling-fanspeeds-in-linux-on-pwm-motherboards-thinkpads-and-asus-eee-pc/) I should also be able to manually modify the `pwm1` file. But the same happens:

```
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ echo 100 > pwm1
bash: pwm1: Permission denied
```

I also tried `editsudo`:

```
szymon@lenovo:/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon3/device$ sudoedit pwm1
sudoedit: pwm1: Operation not permitted
sudoedit: unable to write to pwm1: Operation not permitted
sudoedit: contents of edit session left in /var/tmp/pwm1.XXZLW76B
```

I explored different options, with `sudo su`, `chmod`, but nothing seemed to grant me permissions to edit this file.

**Do you know how I can grant myself permissions to edit this file? I believe this would also solve my issue with the `sudo pwmconfig`.**

Comment: How are you determining the fan speed (sound level, airflow, or ???) as it is without sensor input? And when you say "right after booting up" you mean restart, right? Don't think you could get this from a cold start.

Comment: Also you might read through [**ubuntu CPU overheats**](http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-2134600.html) and as mentioned maybe try [**Jupiter**](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/jupiter-light-weight-power-and-hardware-control-applet.html).

Comment: @user3169, as for determining the fan speed I do it just by listening to the sound - unfortunately `sensors` doesn't provide RPMs of the fan in my case. I've had the laptop for over 3 years now and I know what it sounds like when it's spinning fast. Also, you're right that I was imprecise - "right after booting up" should be after restart. Will correct that.

Comment: does the spin at all? sometimes something small will get stuck in the fan and it just won't spin even though it is getting power and the motor can also fail.

Comment: Yes it spins, but slowly, at a constant speed, with no variations related to the temperature (i.e. regardless of whether the CPU temp is 70C or 95C the rotation speed is the same).

Comment: Possibly the heat sink compound between CPU and heat sink needs replacing. I can see core temps but not a CPU temp, which (in general) should be on the heat sink. As for the fan speed, it depends on what temp. sensor controls it. Also you are confirming CPU usage is low (or usual), right?

Comment: Yes, overall the CPU usage is low/usual. The thing is that if I run several programs and the CPU usage gets higher, the fan doesn't spin up. I guess it has something to do with the `hwmon3/device/pwm1 stuck to 0` message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest thing solved my problem - cleaning the inside of my laptop and applying new thermal paste.

I had my laptop serviced after being unable to resolve the overheating problem in any way myself. I was hoping they would maybe repair / change the fan or something, but the serviceman simply told me that the laptop had a lot of dust inside and just cleaning it and a new thermal paste worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

> sudoedit: unable to write to pwm1: Operation not permitted

this is because:

1. you can fix pwmconfig script replacing `echo $MAX > $1` by `echo
   $MAX | sudo tee $1` and this helps you to resolve trouble with "sudo
   echo"
2. it could be useless according to [this
   article](http://www.aoaforums.com/forum/cooling-and-temperature-monitoring/48770-lenovo-t61p-fan-control-under-linux.html)
   which tell us that we should run first:

   echo "options thinkpad_acpi fan_control=1" /etc/modprobe.d/thinkpad_acpi.conf
   sudo reboot now

now you could successfully run `sudo pwmconfig`

the irony is this also turned useless for me, but could helps you:

> Found the following devices:    hwmon0 is acpitz    hwmon1/device is
>   coretemp    hwmon2/device is thinkpad
>
> Found the following PWM controls:    hwmon2/device/pwm1
>   current value: 0
>
> Giving the fans some time to reach full speed... Found the following
>   fan sensors:    hwmon2/device/fan1_input     current speed: 0 ...
>   skipping!
>
> There are no working fan sensors, all readings are 0. Make sure you
>   have a 3-wire fan connected. You may also need to increase the fan
>   divisors. See doc/fan-divisors for more information.

i don't know what should i do whith that trouble (